# Equation Expansion

Tags: regex, perl, math

I've a requirement where I've to simplify an equation.

I've input like,

```
a + b *((c+d)(e+f))+x
```

and I've to simplify the equation to `a + bce + bcf + bde + bdf + x`

Make a note that, there will be no numerical values assigned. I've to simplify the string equation and get the result in form of equation variables exactly as shown above.

Currently, I made a stack kind of structure where I keep pushing in every character until I encounter "+". Once I do, I dump all the variables from bottom to top and remove the elements from stack until I get the just previous opening bracket ( on the stack. I do this until I get a closing bracket at which I remove everything until I get an opening bracket previous to the one which got closed.

However, the trouble arises when I've something like `(a+b)(e+f)`. I am unable to come up with any logic to do that. Also I am clueless on how I'll be handling redundant brackets, like `((a+b))`

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: 1. *Parse* it into an *abstract syntax tree*. 2. Define a set of *simplification rules*. 3. *Walk the tree* and apply rules until no rule can be applied. It seems you're currently stuck at step 1. You might find that a *parser generator* like [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) could make your life easier. For 2&3, you might be interested in this [SICP video lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/4a-pattern-matching-and-rule-based-substitution/) – but it uses Lisp

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. However, I am unsure how I can use Marpa with the equation simplification. I can make a rule of + & *. But how will I handle the (a+b)*(e+f) as simple a*b will only require concatenation, but something like a*(b+c) requires concatnation of a with both b & c. Besides, I'll have to keep on updating the equation on which I am working. That updation is also one of the problem.

Comment: You use Marpa to parse the string, not for equation "simplification".

Comment: Alright, let me try. Meanwhile, any other suggestion? Or links where I can find some help. It's kind urgent to me as I've to find a solution for this.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Writing a parser is not a trivial task. Learning how to write one is even less. Fortunately, many parsing tutorials use arithmetic expressions as examples.

Comment: A dedicated parser is *the* answer here. Your only hope for doing it faster is if a CPAN module or similar exists that is already a good match. This parser does far more than you need, but you may still be able to use it: http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Math-Symbolic-0.612/lib/Math/Symbolic/Parser.pm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. Discussions about high-level design concepts are more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com. Please read this for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805
BTW, `'ve` can only be used as a contraction for `have` as a helping verb in the perfect tense (as in "I've done that before" or "We've heard a lot of crazy ideas"), not when it indicates possession or in phrasal verbs like "have to".

Comment: You could try asking the question on perlmonks.org